# custom block with content of node according to content type on index page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am new to drupal, and want to display content of a specific content type in to a block. For that I am creating custom block.I am using drupal 6.
In this block I want to display  rotating banner of image in which image will be clickable and some text will be display on image

Actually I have created content type  banner_slideshow. now I want to display records of this content type in a block

any help wil be appriciated

Comment: You need to provide more info, such as, how much content is to be displayed, what will it be sorting by, what is the output supposed to look like, etc...  If you're not going to use views for this, then you will need to write a custom query. When you provide that info, then you can get a decent answer.

Comment: In this block I want to display rotating banner of image in which image will be clickable and some text will be display on image

Answer (score 0):

For this I would recommend using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and the [Views Slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).  After creating your deisred view, you can use Views Slideshow to display a rotating set of content in a block.

See an [example](http://drupalmultimedia.org/slideshow). It will look similar but you can also place the slideshow in a block.

To learn more:
[Video about using/theming Views Slideshow](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42)
[Views Slideshow Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/755010)
[Views Documentation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/views)

Answer (score 0):

Laxman is right, it's probably better to use Views.

You can create a module and you might not need to query the database, depends of what type of information you want to retrieve.

You need to specify that content:

Are you using an image module? are you "pasting" images directly into the node's body? (basically where are those images you want...)